# Code to convert decimal to hexadecimal without using arrays

Tags: c++

I have this code here and I'm trying to do decimal to hexadecimal conversion without using arrays. It is working pretty much but it gives me wrong answers for values greater than 1000. What am I doing wrong? are there any counter solutions? kindly can anyone give suggestions how to improve this code.

```
for(int i = num; i > 0; i = i/16)
{
    temp = i % 16;
    (temp < 10) ? temp = temp + 48 : temp = temp + 55;
    num = num * 100 + temp;
}
cout<<"Hexadecimal = ";
for(int j = num; j > 0; j = j/100)
{   
    ch = j % 100;
    cout << ch;
}
```

Comment: sorry your code is very hard to understand, I have some difficulties to believe that your code is "working pretty much".. why do you add 48 or 55 ?

Comment: Converting a decimal value to hexadecimal just requires basic maths. It in no way requires an array..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know but I'm struggling to do it in code

Comment: I did fixed your code it should work, but this could be find until the num over flows.

Comment: @kingsjester It's re-packing the digits as ASCII characters. 48='0' and 55+10='A'. It's a bit crazy and won't work for big values. But that's the intention.

Comment: @Persixty can you tell me a way to find ABCDEF the other way

Comment: Note that `char` can be evaluated as an integer for these types of operations, so for instance `temp = temp + '0'` (for the digit characters) or `temp = (temp - 10) + 'A'` (for alphabetical ones), which can be slightly clearer for someone reading the code to know that you're basically offsetting an ASCII value. I do question why you're manipulating `num` after though, typically a hex value would be stored as a string (since the numeric representation is the same number regardless of using, say, `255` or `0xFF`).

Comment: I have three points to make about this code. 1) Why two loops? 2) You're using signed values and not outputting a '-' for negative values (it may just work but -1 will be output as ffff) and 3) I can see why big values are causing problems, the first loop is breaking the value down into 4 bit chunks and then reassembling them as 7ish bit chunks so you're going to run out of bits.

Comment: @Xeeshan_65 The mapping works but it's difficult to understand using `magic` numbers 48 and 55. It's also not the best place to do it because it would cause overflow in large values. See my answer.

Comment: @skizz One loop to reverse digits so that the reverse output of %16 and /=16 is the preferred order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of errors in the code. But elements of the approach are clear.

This line sort of works:

```
(temp < 10) ? temp = temp + 48 : temp = temp + 55;
```

But is confusing because it's using 48 and 55 as magic numbers!
It also may lead to overflow.
It's repacking hex digits as decimal character values.

It's also unconventional to use `?:` in that way.

Half the trick of radix output is that each digit is `n%r` followed by `n/r` but the digits come out 'backwards' for conventional left-right output.

This code reverses the hex digits into another variable then reads them out.

So it avoids any overflow risks.
It works with an unsigned value for clarity and a lack of any specification as how to handle negative values.

```
#include <iostream>

void hex(unsigned num){
    unsigned val=num;
    const unsigned radix=16;
    unsigned temp=0;
    while(val!=0){
        temp=temp*radix+val%radix;
        val/=radix;
    }
    do{
        unsigned digit=temp%16;
        char c=digit<10?'0'+digit:'A'+(digit-10);
        std::cout << c;
        temp/=16;
    }while(temp!=0);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(void) {
    hex(0x23U);
    hex(0x0U);
    hex(0x7U);
    hex(0xABCDU);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
23
0
8
ABCD
```

Arguably it's more obvious what is going on if the middle lines of the first loop are:

```
while(val!=0){
    temp=(temp<<4)+(val&0b1111);
    val=val>>4;
}
```

That exposes that we're building `temp` as blocks of 4 bits of `val` in reverse order.
So the value `0x89AB` with be `0xBA98` and is then output in reverse.
I've not done that because bitwise operations may not be familiar.

It's a double reverse!

The mapping into characters is done at output to avoid overflow issues.
Using character literals like `0` instead of integer literals like `44` is more readable and makes the intention clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your code, in the second loop you should exit when ***j > original num***, or set the cumulative sum with non-zero value, I also changed the cumulative num to be long int, rest should be fine.

```
void tohex(int value){
    long int num = 1;
    char ch = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = value; i > 0; i = i/16)
    {
        temp = i % 16;
        (temp < 10) ? temp = temp + 48 : temp = temp + 55;
        num = num * 100 + temp;
    }
    cout<<"Hexadecimal = ";
    for(long int j = num; j > 99; j = j/100)
    {   
        
        ch = j % 100;
        cout << ch;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's a single loop version of the solution to the problem which should work for any sized integer:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char *argv[1])
{
  try
  {
    unsigned
      value = argc == 2 ? stoi(argv[1]) : 64;

    for (unsigned i = numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits; i > 0; i -= 4)
    {
      unsigned
        digit = (value >> (i - 4)) & 0xf;

      cout << (char)((digit < 10) ? digit + 48 : digit + 55);
    }

    cout << endl;
  }
  catch (exception e)
  {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a homework assignment, it is probably related to the chapter on Recursivity. See a [solution](https://ideone.com/0iMMsb) below. To understand it, you need to know

- what a lookup table is
- what recursion is
- how to convert a number from one base to another iteratively
- basic io

```
void hex_out(unsigned n)
{
  static const char* t = "0123456789abcdef"; // lookup table

  if (!n) // recursion break condition
    return;

  hex_out(n / 16);
  std::cout << t[n % 16];
}
```

Note that there is no output for zero. This can be solved simply by calling the recursive function from a second function.

You can also add a second parameter, `base`, so that you can call the function this way:

```
b_out(123, 10); // decimal
b_out(123, 2); // binary
b_out(123, 8); // octal
```

Comment: That is going to be really helpful in future topics. Thanks for the effort. By the way, its not homework.